# Access Tuple model in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models where I have used Tuple to implement it like this

```
@using WorkFlowManagement.Entity
@model Tuple<FormModel, ExternalDataModel>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEdit", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="col-sm-3 paddingVarTop">
        Form Title<span class="required-symbol"> *</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item1.FormTitle, new { @maxlength = "100", @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <span class="required-symbol"> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Item1.FormTitle)</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveForm"> Save</button>
}
```

I want to access the FormTitle in controller how to do it. Below code for controller which currently returns null value for FormTitle:

```
public ActionResult AddEdit(FormModel _Form)
{
   string title = _Form.FormTitle;
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Form");
}
```

Comment: Do not use a `Tuple`. Create a view model, and pass back an instance of that view model

Comment: @StephenMuecke What can be the problem with Tuple?

Comment: @Amit, OP is generating form controls with `name="Item1.FormTitle"` which has no relationship at all to `FormModel`. And the parameter in the POST method cannot be `Tuple<FormModel, ExternalDataModel>` to match the form since a `Tuple` has no parameterl-ess constructor. `Tuple` is the worst thing to use in a view when a form is involved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mvc pass tuple data as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575192/mvc-pass-tuple-data-as-parameter)

Comment: remove new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } since it is not a upload form